# Input type for bookmarks folder tree?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an input field that would be similar in concept to `input type='file'` but I would like for it to display the user's Chrome bookmarks. Is there a specific input type or method I can use to create this?

Comment: Displaying something is output. Not input.

Comment: @MartinBean Yes I know, I would like for the input to allow the user to select a location in their bookmarksNodeTree, so I can return certain bookmarks from the chosen folder.

Comment: There's no such element.